# Codeigniter controller assignments

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i am using codeigniter, I usually end up with all my functions in one controller.

Should i split the functions between multiple controller? if so then how would you know when to seperate them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its based on preference really. I personally group my controllers into areas of function.. IE:

user,index,profile,admin and then use models and a template library to handle loading various views from a single controller.